# React Native Uploading Profile Picture to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, imagepicker

I am attempting to upload a users profile picture to the firebase storage, but every time I click the save button that is supposed to call the code below, I receive an error Unknown, and in the console, the error just says error object Object.

```
const iconChange = () => {
        var options = {
            title: 'Select Profile Picture',
            customButtons: [{ }],
            storageOptions: {
              skipBackup: true,
              path: 'images',
            },
          };
        ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
              } else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
              } else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
              } else {
                const source = { uri: response.uri };
                const fileName = response.fileName;
            
                setPic(response.uri);
                setFileNm(fileName);
                console.log(source);
              }
        });
    }
```

```
const uploadTask = storage.ref('profilePictures/' + auth.currentUser.uid + '/' + fileNm).putFile(profpic)

    uploadTask.on(
        'state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
            const progress = Math.round(
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            );
            setProgress(progress);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            alert(error.message);
        },
        () => {
            storage
            .ref('profilePicture/' + auth.currentUser.uid + '/')
            .child(fileName)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(url => {
                setPic(url);
            })
        }
    )
```

Comment: What is profPic here? `.putFile(profpic)`

Comment: profPic is where I setPic to response.uri